# react with redux and react-router dispatches action twice

Tags: reactjs, action, react-router, react-redux, dispatch

I just started to experiment with react and redux and I face couple of issues on the way.

When I try to render async data on route change the dispatched action is getting fired twice. First is undefined and than comes the real data.

Here is my store

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { routerReducer, routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux'
import reducers from '../reducers'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

const middleware = [ thunk ];
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    middleware.push(createLogger());
}

middleware.push(routerMiddleware(browserHistory));


    // Add the reducer to your store on the `routing` key
    const store = createStore(
        combineReducers({
            reducers,
            routing: routerReducer
        }),
        applyMiddleware(...middleware),

    )

    export default store;
```

reducer

```
export const RESOLVED_GET_PROFILE = 'RESOLVED_GET_PROFILE'

const profileReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_PROFILE':
              return  {profile: action.profile}

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default profileReducer;
```

actions

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';
import Api from '../middleware/Api';

export function getProfile() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(setLoadingProfileState()); // Show a loading spinner
        Api.get('profile').then(profile => {
            dispatch(doneFetchingProfile);
            dispatch(setProfile(profile));
        }).catch(error => {
            dispatch(showError(error));
            throw(error);
        });
    }
}

function setProfile(data) {
    return {
        type: types.SET_PROFILE,
        profile: data
    }
}


function setLoadingProfileState() {
    return {
        type: types.SHOW_SPINNER,
        loaded: false
    }
}

function doneFetchingProfile() {
    return {
        type: types.HIDE_SPINNER,
        loaded: true
    }
}

function showError() {
    return {
        type: types.SHOW_ERROR,
        loaded: false,
        error: 'error'
    }
}
```

and here is my component

```
import React, {PropTypes, Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as profileActions from '../../../actions/profileActions';


class Profile extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            profile:{
                username: '',
                password: '',
                email: ''
            }
        }
        this.onUpdate = this.onUpdate.bind(this)
    }

    onUpdate(event) {
        alert()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //here I dispatch the action
        this.props.actions.getProfile()
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        //this.props.profile on first is undefined and then filled
        const { profile } = this.props.profile

        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {

    return {
        profile: state.default.profile,
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(profileActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Profile);
```

what do I wrong?

[image: console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said `//this.props.profile on first is undefined and then filled`

That's because in the first render, `state.profile` **is** `undefined`, until the request response arrives and the `setProfile` action is dispatched.

There's also the problem Andrew noted that you're calling `dispatch(doneFetchingProfile)`. Since you're using redux-thunk, that will trigger calling `doneFetchingProfile(dispatch, getState)`, but the action `HIDE_SPINNER` will never get dispatched.

---

**UPDATE:** There's nothing wrong with your code. You can see before `SHOW_SPINNER` the output of `console.log(this.props)` and there's no `profile` because there's no `profile` in state as well.

Then when your request succeeds, `profile` is set in state, then passed to your component and then you can see in the log that `profile` is set. Those are not actions dispatched, this is the log of your props.

The first time is undefined because the initial state declared in the reducer is `{}` (there's no `profile` here as well).

If you change

```
const profileReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
```

to

```
const profileReducer = (state = {profile: 'some initial value'}, action) => {
```

you'll see that the first `console.log(this.props)` will show `profile` with the value `'some initial value'` and then change to the remote data.

Comment: so I tried dispatch(doneFetchingProfile(profile)) and return profile but even like that is the same. How do I refactor the code to be fired once with the data?

Comment: @fefe I don't understand. How are you looking what actions are dispatched? According to the code `SET_PROFILE` should be dispatched only once. But `state.profile` assumes 2 values: starts with `undefined` and then is set to the correct data, after the above action is dispatched.

Comment: I made a screenshot from console

Comment: @fefe I updated my comment. There's nothing wrong with the code. That's how async works.

Answer (score 1):

This is what happening here

1. Your component render and show **undefined** on console because there is no profile data so far.
2. After component mount it call componentDidmount which fire an action to fetch data from url.
3. You get data from api and update the redux state which update your component as well.
4. Therefore you render function is called again and this time it **shows the profile data**.

There is nothing dispatching two times. The code is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You dispatching 2 actions

```
dispatch(doneFetchingProfile);
dispatch(setProfile(profile));
```

First of them have no data, and it's look like tihs action set to state some data and update your component.

Comment: Actually, with redux-thunk that will simply not dispatch any action regarding "set profile"